# antlr4 grammar with negative option

Tags: antlr4

In antlr4 I want to define a string but exclude from it the combination := permitting the respective single characters. What is syntax to define the grammar

```
EQUAL : '=';
NUMBER: DIGIT+;
DIGIT   :   ('0'..'9');
LITERALEQUAL: ((CHAR | NUMBER | EQUAL | OTHERS) ' '?)+;
fragment CHAR   :[a-z]| [A-Z];
fragment OTHERS:  '.' | '/' | ':' | '-' | '#' | '?' | '&' | '_' | '[' | ']' | '^' | ';' | '"' | '=';
```

Comment: Roger, did my answer not make sense to you?  Can I help further?

Answer (score 0):

As  long as you **don't make a lexer rule or implicit token** like:

```
stmt : value ':=' something ;  <-- implicit token
```

or

```
BADEquals : ':=' ; <-- explicit lexer definition
```

your eventual grammar won't allow it if your goal is to a allow `:` and `=` but exclude the combination `:=` .